# ReplySubject from array

Tags: android, rx-java

In the context of a android application I want to create an `ReplaySubject` from an array that I retrieve from the saved bundle.

So far I have:

```
subject = ReplaySubject.create();
for (SomeDto dto : dtos) {
 subject.onNext(dto);
}
```

I was hoping for a more straight forward way that will avoid the iteration.

Comment: I faced the same problem, but there seems to be nothing else in the API to create a ReplaySubject. There should probably be a fundamental reason for this constraint on Subject creations. One should investigate between the core implementation difference between Observables and Subjects (i.e. cold and hot Observables).

Comment: @ffarquet I've also posted a question on the group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/__NBWp6pb6o just in case

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject#replaysubject)?

If the DTO list you are retrieving from the bundle is constant and the subscribers don't need to be notified of changes after being retrieved from the bundle you can just use a standard Observable no need to use a Subject.

```java
List<SomeDto> dtos;    // Get list of SomeDto from bundle.
Observable<SomeDto> dtoObservable = Observable.from(dtos);
```

Each time a subscription to dtoObserbale is made it will replay all the items.

If your subscribers need to notified of changes to the DTO list in addition to the initial values then the way you are doing it is just fine.

**EDIT:** Another idea you might like. Create an observable from the DTOs retrieved from the Bundle. Then concatenate it with the DTO subject.

```java
List<SomeDto> dtos;    // Get list of SomeDto from bundle.
ReplaySubject<SomeDto> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
Observable<SomeDto> dtoObservable = 
    Observable
        .from(dtos)
        .concatWith(subject);

// At some point later.
subject.onNext(anotherDto);
```

Each subscriber will see all values. Here's an example with strings:

```java
final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
final ReplaySubject<String> stringsSubject = ReplaySubject.create();

final Observable<String> stringObservable =
        Observable
                .from(strings)
                .concatWith(stringsSubject);

stringObservable
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                logger.v("stringObservable1 - " + s);
            }
        });

stringsSubject.onNext("3");

stringObservable
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                logger.v("stringObservable2 - " + s);
            }
        });

stringsSubject.onNext("4");

stringObservable
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                logger.v("stringObservable3 - " + s);
            }
        });

stringsSubject.onNext("5");
```

Outputs the following:

```java
stringObservable1 - 1
stringObservable1 - 2
stringObservable1 - 3
stringObservable2 - 1
stringObservable2 - 2
stringObservable2 - 3
stringObservable1 - 4
stringObservable2 - 4
stringObservable3 - 1
stringObservable3 - 2
stringObservable3 - 3
stringObservable3 - 4
stringObservable1 - 5
stringObservable2 - 5
stringObservable3 - 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (updated the typo in the inial post), my list is not constant and I need the functionality of a Subject in my code.